# Event Relative Time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

So here's the scenario:

My application has a transaction section in it. It logs actions and stores the time as a UNIX timestamp (UTC).

So yesterday I got paid £100.00 and this was logged into the database with a unix timestamp of 1477762205 which equates to Sat, 29 Oct 2016 17:30:05 UTC/GMT.

(This is 19:30 local time for me)

My application (written in PHP) outputs using a datetime object and passing in the output timezone (Europe/London).

Yesterday it outputted correctly local time as 19:30 and due to the clock time change this morning at 2am it now reads 18:30.

This is technically correct but if I remember back relative to the event when logging the transaction in the first place this will now seem incorrect as I remember it being 19:30 local time.

My question is what is the best way to output the time from UTC, relative to the event? Do I need to store the timezone with the UTC log to determine the timezone at the point the log took place?

Code:

When storing the log:

(This is part of a logger class I'm creating)

```
    if($dateTime == null) {

        $dateTime = time();

    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO `".$this->databaseName."`.`log`(`datetime`,`action`) VALUES(?, ?);";
    if(!$stmt = $this->database->prepare($query)) {

        return $this->database->error;

    }

    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$dateTime,$action);

    $stmt->execute();
```

When outputting this:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$dateTime->setTimestamp($log->timeStamp);
$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
echo $dateTime->format('d/m/Y H:i');
```

Techincally correct output: 29/10/2016 18:30

But I wish for it to display being DST aware relative to the actual timestamp, not the DST relative to now.

So I wish for it to output: 29/10/2016 19:30

Comment: What do you mean exactly with UTC Unix timestamp?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean, because it isn't very clear?

Comment: Ok so at 19:30 UK time on 29th, I logged a transaction. The unix timestamp for this was 1477762205. When outputting to the php page: $datetime = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$datetime->setTimestamp($timeStamp);
echo $datetime->format($format);

Pre 30th it displays as 1930 for europe/london. but post 30th it displays as 1830. I want it to display as 19:30. It is like PHP is not being DST aware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's summarise the expected local values for `1477762205` Unix timestamp:

- UTC:    **17:30:05** (UTC,  +0000)
- London: **18:30:05** (BST,  +0100 aka 3600, DST=1)
- Madrid: **19:30:05** (CEST, +0200 aka 7200, DST=1)

Stuff seems to work as expected as long as you use city-based time zone identifiers:

```
foreach (['UTC', 'Europe/London', 'Europe/Madrid'] as $time_zone_id) {
    $dt = new DateTime('@1477762205');
    $tz = new DateTimeZone($time_zone_id);
    $dt->setTimezone($tz);
    echo $time_zone_id . ': ' . $dt->format('H:i:s [e=T, O]') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

```
UTC: 17:30:05 [UTC=UTC, +0000]
Europe/London: 18:30:05 [Europe/London=BST, +0100]
Europe/Madrid: 19:30:05 [Europe/Madrid=CEST, +0200]
```

As soon as we use named zones acronyms, strange things happen:

```
foreach (['UTC', 'BST', 'GMT', 'CEST', 'CET'] as $time_zone_id) {
    $dt = new DateTime('@1477762205');
    $tz = new DateTimeZone($time_zone_id);
    $dt->setTimezone($tz);
    echo $time_zone_id . ': ' . $dt->format('H:i:s [e=T, O]') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

```
UTC: 17:30:05 [UTC=UTC, +0000]
BST: 17:30:05 [BST=BST, +0000]
GMT: 17:30:05 [GMT=GMT, +0000]
CEST: 18:30:05 [CEST=CEST, +0100]
CET: 18:30:05 [CET=CET, +0100]
```

There's probably some relation with the information (or lack of it) about time zone transitions available in the underlying database:

```
$dt = new DateTime('@1477762205');
foreach (['UTC', 'BST', 'Europe/London', 'CEST', 'Europe/Madrid'] as $time_zone_id) {
    $tz = new DateTimeZone($time_zone_id);
    $dt->setTimezone($tz);
    echo $time_zone_id . PHP_EOL;
    echo '- Time zone offset: ' . $tz->getOffset($dt) . ' seconds' . PHP_EOL;

    $transitions = $tz->getTransitions(mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2016), mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 2016));
    if ($transitions===false) {
        echo '- Error fetching transitions' . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo '- ' . count($transitions) . ' transitions found' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

```
UTC
- Time zone offset: 0 seconds
- 1 transitions found
BST
- Time zone offset: 0 seconds
- Error fetching transitions
Europe/London
- Time zone offset: 3600 seconds
- 3 transitions found
CEST
- Time zone offset: 3600 seconds
- Error fetching transitions
Europe/Madrid
- Time zone offset: 7200 seconds
- 3 transitions found
```

It's really hard to say how much of this is a plain bug and how much is counter-intuitive but documented; the PHP bug database is crowded with *not a bug* entries which are indeed a misunderstanding but I've personally found weird but actual bugs in date calculations involving DST boundaries.

Comment: This works but the problem is with the conversion. If I construct a datetime with null and datetimezone utc and then set the timestamp I get the UTC time. But I need to convert to Europe/London time as of yesterday but if I do setTimezone europe/london then it converts to what it would be today but not when the actual timestamp was. Sorry if I'm not being clear. It doesn't seem to take daylight savings into consideration

Comment: Nope I'm storing using php's time() method.

Comment: Techincally I get the correct result but I wish to display the converted time as if I was displaying 1 second after the timestamp. So that DST is still applied for timestamps before the date when DST is removed from the UK's time. So even if UTC this timestamp is correct with today's timezone, I wish for php to be DST aware so it converts dates to local in the past based on what the conversion would be at that specific point in time, instead of what it would be now.

Comment: @DanTheDJ1 Please check my brand new answer.